# Set Toolbar logo in XML

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar

Is it possible to set Toolbar logo in xml? I have tried this so far:

1.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    android:logo="@drawable/my_logo"
    />
```

2.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    app:logo="@drawable/my_logo"
    />
```

---

EDIT

I'm using toolbar as an actionbar in my AppCompatActivity:

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
```

I'm able to set logo from code:

```
((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar)).setLogo(R.drawable.my_logo);
```

But I'd like to set logo either from layout XML or from Style/Theme XML.

Comment: Your code  1. and code 2. are exactly same and app:logo="@drawable/my_logo" does set a logo in my toolbar.

Comment: @SunilKumar they are not the same -- the first uses `android:logo`, the second -- `app:logo`

Comment: Oh, sorry. Also i concluded that we should not use toolbar if we want to place a logo in it. Toolbar does not provide any ways to customize the logo size and position.

Comment: @SunilKumar I believe it only allows this with a custom inner layout, as [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30851889/369317) suggests.

Answer (score 13):

Do Change

```
app:logo="@drawable/my_logo"
```

to

```
app:navigationIcon="@drawable/my_logo"
```

**UPDATE**

Add Linearlayout into your toolbar xml tag.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/media_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="new post image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I'm not interested in customizing navigation icon ("back/up button"), but in customizing the logo (which is on the right of navigation icon).

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to set standard logo, not introducing a custom child(ren).

Comment: I think by customization you can achieve your desired output, let me know if it would be possible with any toolbar xml attributes.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can, but it will not work well with name on Toolbar. You can just put ImageView into the body of Toolbar, like you do this with Layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <ImageView
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   app:logo="@drawable/my_logo"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
```

Better if you will do this from the code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.my_logo);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to set standard logo, not introducing a custom child.

Answer (score 4):

Using xml only

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

<style name="ActionbarLogo">
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/ic_menu_camera</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionbarLogo</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Now apply AppTheme.NoActionBar theme to your activity( and if you want to remove toolbar title use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); after setSupportActionBar(toolbar);)

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

To display logo icon set this icon at runtime in ActionBar.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(@drawable/my_logo);
```

Comment: I'm interested in doing it from XML (either layout or style).

Answer (score 1):

this could be the answer:

```
    <Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/atc_toolbar"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:navigationIcon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass"
        android:logo="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
        android:title="My application">
    </Toolbar>
```

In my case result looks like this:

[Toolbar with Logo and Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P2BJ.jpg)

If for some reasons logo does not show up then try to start a new, fresh project, add only layout_width, layout_height, id and logo attributes. Remember to add toolbar in onCreate via setActionBar or setSupportActionBar.
Regards,
P.

Answer (score 0):

In your code put
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.icon);
It will work

Comment: He is clearly asking for the XML way, not Java code.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. Create this file in your layout foulder:

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_logo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/my_logo"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Do this in your activity.java:

```java
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.my_logo);
```

And this in your activity.xml

```xml
<include
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```